# Why I got position at 0? When it should be 1

Tags: java, arraylist, position, indexof, autoboxing

I learn Java, now I'm at ArrayList, I wrote some methods about banking, when I want to add a new customer at a specific branch, the position always return 0. This is the source code of the methods that I'm talking about:

- **The instances in Main class :**

  ```
  public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static Bank newBank = new Bank("BMCE");
  ```
- **Main class (static method to add a new customer):**

  ```
  public static void addNewCostumer(){
  System.out.println("Choose a branch :");
  String branchChoosed = scanner.nextLine();
  Branches branches = newBank.queryBranch(branchChoosed);
  if(branches == null){
      System.out.println("There are a problem, or you are entered a wrong name of branch");

  }
  else{
      System.out.println("Enter the name costumer :");
      String nameOfCostumer = scanner.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter the transaction number :");
      double transactions = scanner.nextDouble();
      scanner.nextLine();
      if(newBank.addNewCostumer(branches,nameOfCostumer,transactions)){
          System.out.println("The costumer was created in branch name :"+branches.getNameOfBranch());


      }else{

          System.out.println("Sorry you dindn't create a costumer in "+branches.getNameOfBranch()+" Try again please :)");

      }

  }
  ```
- **The instances in Bank class:**

  ```
  private String name;
  private ArrayList<Branches> branchesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  ```
- **Bank class:**

  ```
  public boolean addNewCostumer(Branches nameOfExistingBranch,String nameOfNewCostumer,double newTransaction){
  int position = findBranch(nameOfExistingBranch);


  if(position<0){
      System.out.println("There is not branch with this name");
      return false;
  }
  else{
      if(this.branchesArrayList.get(position).findCostumer(nameOfNewCostumer)>=0){
          System.out.println("You have already an existing costumer with that name");
          return false;
      }
      else{

          this.branchesArrayList.get(position).addNewCostumer(nameOfNewCostumer,newTransaction);
          return true;

      }

  }

  }
  ```
- **The method that finds branches:**

  ```
  public int findBranch(Branches branches){
  int position = this.branchesArrayList.indexOf(branches);
  if(position>=0){

      return position;

  }
  else
      return -1;
  }
  ```
- ***The inputs :***

  0-Mdiq
  1-Casa
  2-Rabat

When I add a new customer to Rabat or Casa Branch the customer always records in Mdiq (Position 0).

Comment: BTW *public int indexOf(Object o)
Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.*  how have you implemented `equals`

Comment: My expectation is that they *haven't*  overwritten `equals`. However, this means that `indexOf` does  a `==` check, which is more strict

Comment: @JClassic Agree with what you are saying, but I was banking on a badly implemented `equals`

Comment: You showed us a lot of code we don't need, while failing to post the code we do need to see. As the Javadoc for [`ArrayList::indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) explains, your override of `Object::equals` via [`Objects.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#compare(T,T,java.util.Comparator))  the mechanism by which the list searches for your object. Your `equals` method is likely flawed, but you don't show it so we don't know for certain.

Comment: Always **search Stack Overflow** thoroughly before posting. Comparing objects for equality has been covered countless times already.

Answer (score 0):

I' found a mistake in my code so the problem was solved.
In a query method I wrote `this.branchesArrayList.get(0);` instead of using position as a parameter.